# Reading text from XML nodes using Python's libxml2

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am a first time `XPath` user and need to be able to get the text values of these different elements.. for instance `time`, `title`, etc.. I am using the `libxml2` module in Python and so far have not had much luck getting just the values of the text I need. The code below here only returns the element tags.. i need the values.. any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

I'm using this code:

```
doc = libxml2.parseDoc(xmlOutput)
result = doc.xpathEval('//*')
```

With the following document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT SYSTEM "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/sca/scan_list_output.dtd">
<SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT>
<RESPONSE>
<DATETIME>2012-01-22T01:21:53Z</DATETIME>
<SCAN_LIST>
  <SCAN>
    <REF>scan/2343423</REF>
    <TYPE>Scheduled</TYPE>
    <TITLE><![CDATA[customer 1 5/20/2012]]></TITLE>
    <USER_LOGIN>user1</USER_LOGIN>
    <LAUNCH_DATETIME>2012-02-21T04:11:05Z</LAUNCH_DATETIME>
    <STATUS>
      <STATE>Finished</STATE>
    </STATUS>
    <TARGET><![CDATA[13.3.3.2, 13.8.8.10, 13.10.12.60, 13.10.12.11...]]></TARGET>
  </SCAN>
</SCAN_LIST>
</RESPONSE>
</SCAN_LIST_OUTPUT>
```

Comment: I'd strongly, _strongly_ suggest `lxml.etree`, which uses the C libxml2 library under-the-hood but provides a far friendlier API.

Comment: You should really post that as an answer instead :-)

Comment: The question isn't really about XPath -- the XPath call you're making works perfectly; your question is about how to deal with the values it returns, which aren't any different from the element objects you'd get iterating directly (ie. _not_ using XPath). Updated summary and tagging appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `getContent()` on each returned `xmlNode` object to retrieve the associated text. Note that this is recursive -- to non-recursively access text content in libxml2, you'll want to retrieve the associated text node under the element, and call `.getContent()` on *that*.

That said, this would be easier if you used `lxml.etree` (a higher-level Python API, still backing into the C libxml2 library) instead of the Python libxml2; in that case, it's simply `element.text` to access the associated content as a string.

Comment: .getContent() did the trick!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH :).. any idea where a good references or documentation for the rest of the functions would be? the api docs I was going through were horrible and I never came across .getContent().. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1377384 I found `getContent()` by running `help(result[0])` at the REPL and reading its output.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Mark Pilgrim's *Dive Into Python 3*, [Chapter 12. XML](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/xml.html)

The chapter starts with short course to XML (general talk but with the Atom Syndication Feed example), then it continues with the standard `xml.etree.ElementTree` and continues with third party [lxml](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/xml.html#xml-lxml) that implements more with the same interface (full XPATH 1.0, based on libxml2).