# XPath in Python using xmllint2

Tags: python, xpath

I try to make a query with xpath in python in order to print differrent parts of a kml file.

The problem is: when I make my query I have very strange results.

Here is my code:

```
import libxml2

rss=libxml2.parseDoc(open('/home/julien/xpath/SUPPORT2.kml').read())
#print doc

node=rss.xpathEval('//Placemark')
print node
```

And here is the result :

```
[<xmlNode (Placemark) object at 0xa3e2acc>, <xmlNode (Placemark) object at0xa3e2b6c>,     <xmlNode (Placemark) object at 0xa3e2d4c>, <xmlNode (Placemark)
object at 0xa3e2dac>, <xmlNode (Placemark) object at 0xa3e2dec>, <xmlNode 
Placemark) object at 0xa3e2dcc>, <xmlNode (Placemark) object at 0xa3e2d8c>, 
<xmlNode (Placemark) object at 0xa3e2e0c>, <xmlNode (Placemark) object at 
0xa3e2eac>, <xmlNode (Placemark) object at 0xa3e2fec>, <xmlNode (Placemark) 
object at 0xa3e2f0c>, <xmlNode (Placemark) object at 0xa3e2f2c>, <xmlNode 
(Placemark) object at 0xa3e2f4c>, <xmlNode (Placemark) object at 0xa3e2f6c>, 
<xmlNode (Placemark) object at 0xa3e2f8c>]
```

What can explain this result? And what could I add in my code to make my query work?

Comment: Why not use `lxml`? It wraps `libxml2` in a *far* nicer API.

Comment: Other than that, the code works just fine. You found multiple nodes.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. I prefer xmllint because I'm more accustomed to it than lxml.  Yes, I have multiple nodes but I have not the part of the code related to the query. And when I use the same synthax in xpath (outside of python), it works. I really don't understand !

Comment: 1) What does your KML look like; and 2) what results did you expect? How are they different from the results you got?

Comment: My kml is composed of multiple placemarks. Each placemark looks like : `<Placemark>  <ExtendedData>  <SchemaData schemaUrl="#SUPPORT">  
            <SimpleData name="ID_SUP">SUPSV17270000001</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ID_ABO">TRONR0033016508ABO</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="SUPPORT">Arbre</SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
      </Placemark>`  And I'd want to have all that code when I specify the `node=rss.xpathEval('//Placemark')` in my script. But the problem is that I have these kind of `0xa3e2dac`results.

Comment: Just curious, why does the title say xmllint? I only see the code using libxml2.

Answer (score 0):

The result you're getting is a list of xmlNode objects. They are apparently correct results. You asked Python to print (a representation of) the node list. The string representation of an xmlNode object is this:

```
"<xmlNode (NodeName) object at MemoryAddress>"
```

However, you want to see them as serialized text ("`<Placemark> ...`"). In order to get that, call [serialize()](http://pyxmlsec.labs.libre-entreprise.org/docs/html/libxml2.xmlCore-class.html#serialize) on each xmlNode in the list:

```
nodeList = rss.xpathEval('//Placemark')
for node in nodeList:
    print node.serialize('utf-8')
```

This can be useful for giving you assurance about the contents of the results from XPath. However if you're doing further processing with those nodes, the serialized strings are probably not what you want.

See also: [Reading text from XML nodes using Python's libxml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694767/reading-text-from-xml-nodes-using-pythons-libxml2)

Comment: @Julien: You're welcome - Glad to hear it. If you're satisfied with an answer, don't forget to click the green check mark to "accept". :-)